# Angular7 Typescript Cannot read property 'countryId',stateId, of null

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a javascript code how to do null check for this code

Cannot read property 'countryId',stateId of null,How to resolve this error
I am getting cannot read property of null errors for country,state,address everything

```
  location: {
                  countryId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                    ? textHeader === 'SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_UPDATE'
                      ? parseInt(this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId, 10)
                      : this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                    : null,
                  stateId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.stateId
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.stateId
                    : null,
                  stateName: this.requestAddresses[index].location.stateName
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.stateName
                    : null,
                  cityName: this.requestAddresses[index].location.cityName
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.cityName
                    : null,
                  provinceName: this.requestAddresses[index].location.provinceName
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.provinceName
                    : null,
                  postalCode: this.requestAddresses[index].location.postalCode
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.postalCode
                    : null,
                  addressLine1: this.requestAddresses[index].location.addressLine1
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.addressLine1
                    : null,
                  addressLine2: this.requestAddresses[index].location.addressLine2
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.addressLine2
                    : null,
                  addressLine3: this.requestAddresses[index].location.addressLine3
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.addressLine3
                    : null,
                  addressLine4: this.requestAddresses[index].location.addressLine4
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.addressLine4
                    : null,
                  poBoxNumber: this.requestAddresses[index].location.poBoxNumber
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.poBoxNumber
                    : null,
                  internalId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.internalId
                    ? this.requestAddresses[index].location.internalId
                    : null,
                },
              };
              addressesEntity.push(tempObj);
            });
```

Comment: You can write like this: this.requestAddresses[index].location && this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId, but please change the title from javascript to typescript

Comment: `this.requestAddresses[index].location` is null.

Comment: if (this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId) {}

Comment: Hi can you answer the question exactly please

Comment: Hi Arsen i wrote like this  location: {
                         countryId: this.requestAddresses[index].location && this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                        ? textHeader === 'SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_UPDATE'
                          ? parseInt(this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId, 10)
                          : this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                        : null,

Comment: But for more simplicity you can write this in if/else block

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the value in key 'location' is null/undefined. Try this short-circuiting method:

```
countryId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                    ? textHeader === 'SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_UPDATE'
                      ? parseInt(this.requestAddresses[index].location && this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId, 10)
                      : this.requestAddresses[index].location && this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                    : null,
```

Or, if you have lodash installed:

```
import { get } from 'lodash';
...
countryId: this.requestAddresses[index].location.countryId
                ? textHeader === 'SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_UPDATE'
                  ? parseInt(get(this.requestAddresses[index].location, 'countryId'), 10)
                  : get(this.requestAddresses[index].location, 'countryId')
                : null,
```

Comment: You checked only in one place, but there are two more cases

Comment: Yeah, looks like I missed it. Sorry about that, updated now. Thanks, @ArsenGalloghlyan!

Comment: can you check my updated question and answer please Tashi

Comment: can you check my updated question and answer please @ArsenGalloghlyan